# Hardware acceleration in video playback

Tags: gpu, amd-processor, hardware-acceleration

I have ubuntu system with amd apu a6 llano. when I play hd videos on ubuntu using vlc or some other media player it takes so much cpu usage but when I play same video on windows 7 it takes just 5% cpu usage. I installed latest amd fglrx drivers but why it doesn't  make use of gpu decoding playing video like windows 7.